# Scala: check combination of two variables

Tags: scala

I want to check if two variables taken in any order can be paired into a specific pair. Basically the below, only it doesn't work because of type erasure at runtime

```
def combination[A,B](x: Any, y: Any): Option[(A, B)] =
  (x, y) match {
    case (a: A, b: B) => Some(a, b)
    case (b: B, a: A) => Some(a, b)
    case _ => None
```

Is there another way to do the same which would work...

Comment: Can you limit the type of the two arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, since it wasn't clear in your message, if you want to pattern-match against a pair of *constants* (a, b), you may want to consider back-ticks instead of what you're doing :

```
case (`a`, `b`) => Some(a, b)
```

On the other hand if you are trying to retrieve the elements of a pair of any values of type (A, B), in any order, you can do it for non-primitive types (i.e. subtypes of `AnyRef`) :

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def combination[A, B](x: AnyRef, y: AnyRef)(implicit tagA: ClassTag[A], tagB: ClassTag[B]): Option[(A, B)] = (x, y) match {
  case (a: A, b: B) => Some(a, b)
  case (b: B, a: A) => Some(a, b)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I needed.